# Uppercase letter bug in class/function name of included php when locale tr_TR

Tags: php, locale, case-sensitive

When I set locale as tr_TR and run this code:

```
ini_set("error_reporting",E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8');

require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

$PHPMail = new PHPMailer();

$PHPMail->IsSMTP();
```

class.phpmailer.php content is:

```
class PHPMailer {

    public function IsSMTP() {
        $this->Mailer = 'smtp';
    }
}
```

I recive this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::IsSMTP() in test.php on line 10
```

If don't set locate="tr_TR" or don't use upper-case "I" or class not included, I don't get an error message.

Note: Turhish "I" in the lower-case letter is equivalent "ı"(no-dot)

Comment: Did you check that `$PHPMail` contains a valid instance of `PHPMailer`? In other words, was there a problem instantiating the object? Do you really want to use `LC_ALL` for `setlocale()`?

Comment: Does your system have that locale installed?

Comment: Other functions working. In other class/functions have also these problems. Problem in Turhish and letter "I"

Comment: Check out the documentation on `setlocale()` lots of problems mentioned around use of `LC_ALL`.  That is why I question whether you really need that setting.

Answer (score 0):

Put or edit this line on apache configuration file. (on debian wheezy /etc/apache2/envvar file)

`# export LANG`

`export LANG=tr_TR.UTF-8`